# VBA Macro Speed Up

Tags: vba, excel

I would appreciate some help on the following VBA Macro problem,
screenshot here:

[image: Excel Data]

I have to compare the data in 2 columns - Index & Sec_Index. In case of a match it should check which Values is assigned to the Sec_Index and fill a "1" to the matching Value column corresponding to Index and "0" for the other Value columns (I hope the screenshot explains it better)

I wrote a short macro which works good. However I have huge amounts of data - both Index columns contain at least 400000-500000 lines. This makes my code useless since it will take extreme long durations to execute.

Is there a way to make this work? I read about Variant arrays, but I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: You could just do this with a formula. But if you want assistance with code, then you'll need to show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this formula (if Excel 2007 or above):

```
=COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$5,$B2,$I$2:$I$5,"A")
```

into C2 and copy it down and across; just change "A" to "B" and "C".

**Added** In view of the number of rows, I would import the data into MS Access, create a Crosstab Query, then copy this data back to Excel.

Comment: @buckminst. Thank you. You could use $B2 as well, so that you can copy across.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your suggestion seems to work, however, it takes to long to perform the calculations. For the amount of data i've got (400000-500000 rows x 10 Columns/Values), it would take hours. Thats why i was wondering if a macro wouldn't be faster.

Comment: A macro won't be faster IMO. A database would be, or possibly a PowerPivot table - a free add-in for Excel 2010+. Bung the data into Access, create a Crosstab Query, then copy this back to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not overly robust but does work. Not sure how quickly this will compare to what you may have had?

It did about `60,000` rows with `25 keys` in about `5 seconds`.

**Edit: Added timer to function.**

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
public Sub main()
Dim t As Long
t = GetTickCount
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Arr1(), Arr() As Double
    Dim x, y, i, j As Double
    Dim v As String
    x = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    y = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    Range("c2", "e" & x + 2) = 0
    ReDim Arr1(x)
    ReDim Arr2(y)
    i = 0
    Do Until Cells(i + 2, 2) = ""
        Arr1(i) = Cells(i + 2, 2)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 0
    Do Until Cells(i + 2, 8) = ""
        Arr2(i) = Cells(i + 2, 2)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    i = 0
    Do Until i > UBound(Arr1)
        j = 0
        Do Until j > UBound(Arr2)
            If Arr1(i) = Arr2(j) Then
                v = Cells(Arr2(j) + 1, 9)
                Select Case v
                    Case "a"
                        Cells(i + 2, 3) = 1
                    Case "b"
                        Cells(i + 2, 4) = 1
                    Case "c"
                        Cells(i + 2, 5) = 1
                End Select
                Exit Do
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox GetTickCount - t, , "Milliseconds"
End Sub
```